# Basis for Ker(T), Range(T) of Linear Transformation without the Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T: $M_{2x2}(R) \to R^2$ be the linear transformation defined by

$$
        T\left(
       \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
        a - b \\
        c - d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

What I think I know: (a) Find Ker(T), a basis for Ker(T) and nullity(T)
solving the homogenous system yields $a=b, c=d$, then 
$Ker(T)=span \{ \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},  \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \}$
It follows that the Basis for Ker(T) is the two matrices above and nullity(T) = 2

What I don't know: (b) Find a basis for Range(T) and Rank(T)

I understand that if you have a Matrix A representing the linear transformation the Range(T) is just the Col(A).  How do I find a basis for the Range when I am missing that Matrix?

It also seems that a simple observation would be that $Rank(T)=2$ because

$dim(v)=nullity(T)+rank(T)$  and thus $Rank(T) = 4 - 2 = 2$

but I am unaware of how this observation helps me solve the problem at hand.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Rank($T$) is $2$ means the dimension of the Range space of $T$ is $2$ and this a subspace of $\mathbb {R}^2$, so actually the range of T is the whole $\mathbb {R}^2$, so you can choose any basis of $\mathbb {R}^2$, that will be the basis for Range of $T$

Comment: @R.Singh thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank of $T$ is $2$ and the dimension of the space of column vectors is $2$. Therefore the image is the whole space of column vectors: $\Bbb R^2$.